# Passing all get argument to another link php

Tags: php

I have a PHP page(index.php) which will have some arguments in the url(i.e through $_GET), i need to pass those arguments to a hyperlink which is in the index.php, that takes us to new page (i.e newpage.php).
What i can do is get all the arguments and pass them directly to the link, with finding each argument using $_GET, but is it possible to do this without taking out each variable?

Comment: All your need is in the `$_SERVER`

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] will have a string of all the URL parameters that you would normally access via the $_GET method without having to know what has been set or not.

So, depending on your use case, you can use that server variable to output to your hyperlink. Just beware of outputting raw URL parameters, because that does leave you potentially open to XSS. It's recommended to validate inputs before outputting them to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the URL parameters using PHP_URL_QUERY and pass those parameters to your link.

**Example :**

$arg = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);

action = "https://www.example.com/newpage.php?echo $arg;